# Mobile Android App crash when i click a button to the next screen

Tags: android, delphi, crash, rad-studio

I'm new in Delphi and I build a simple mobile android app with login and register screen. When I'm running the app on desktop win 64 it runs fine but when I'm running it in my phone (android 64, Samsung A5) and push the register button to navigate to the Register screen from Login screen it crashes.
The code of the button:

```
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TRegister_form, Register_form);
  Register_form.Show;
  Application.MainForm := Register_form;
  Login_form.Close;
  Login_form.Free;
  Login_form := nil;
end;
```

Is there any ideas of a better way or why it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at documentation for [MainForm](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.MainForm) you can see that MainForm is a read only at Runtime and therefore it can not be changed

> MainForm cannot be modified at run time (it is read-only at run time).

You will have to use different approach to achieve what you wish. There are many examples of how to handle login or splash forms in Delphi available on the internet. There are even some answers to questions about this same topic here on Stack Overflow.

Also, the first form created by `Application.CreateForm` automatically becomes the `Application.MainForm`, so your trying to do so in the code you posted would be meaningless anyway - `Register_Form` is already the `Application.MainForm`.